# Getting the last record in a TOP n PERCENT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the boundaries of certain percentiles in my data, i.e. what value lies at the 10% mark and therefore what value would someone have to exceed to be in the top 10%.

I can get that value by running a query such as:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [Time] 
    FROM Scores 
    WHERE Lesson = 1 
    ORDER BY [Time];
```

... and then referring to the last record returned.

Does anyone know what query I could run to directly get that value? The ORDER BY clause seems to cause all the problems as I haven't been able to have the above run as a sub-query and the fact that it's already an integral part of the query prevents using it to get the bottom record. I'm sure there must be an easy way though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an outer query to select the top row:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 Time
FROM    (    
        SELECT  TOP 10 PERCENT [Time] 
        FROM    Scores 
        WHERE   Lesson = 1 
        ORDER BY 
                Time
        ) as Top10
 ORDER BY
        Time DESC
```

Comment: That works, thanks. The only issue was that because I'm using SQL Server (2008) I had to add an alias for the sub-query, so after the closing bracket I added " AS Top10". My fault for not specifying what I was using. Thanks again!

Comment: @BinarySolo: That's true for most databases, answer edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MIN(Time)
FROM    (    
        SELECT  TOP 10 PERCENT [Time] 
        FROM    Scores 
        WHERE   Lesson = 1 
        ORDER BY 
                Time
)
```

This will return the minimum value of [Time] on the top 10 percent values

Comment: Thanks, this works, just that in this case I needed MAX rather than MIN. I wonder which is faster, this or Andomar's?